# Pasword in NET USE -command on Python

Tags: python

Is there a possibility that net use -command on python doesn't work correctly when there is a exclamation mark (!) in the password?

```
os.system(r"NET USE z: \\1.10.0.1\dir /USER:username mypasword!")
```

I got the username and the password correct in the code but when I convert the script to an .exe and run it on command line, I got permission error that indicates that username or the password is wrong.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your script works for passwords that do not contain `!`?

Comment: not yet, but I'm going to. Still waiting sys admin to change the password for location that I try to use. 

I tried my script to a drive that doesn't need pasword and it works.

Comment: I confirmed that script works when there is not exclamation mark in the password. I believe that it is an issue with all the other special characters also. Numbers other hand is ok.

Comment: Does the `NET USE...` command work for passwords with `!` when executed from the command line?